# Add an Asset to a store when my App is installed in shopify

Tags: assets, shopify, code-snippets

I need to add a snippet to the shopify store template during App installation.
What is the right way to do this?

I have already created a test store, developed an app in ROR 
and app installation is done successfully. Now need to create the snippet during installation process.

Answer (score 1):

1. Take a look at this repo: https://github.com/Shopify/shopify_app
2. Edit `config/initializers/shopify_app.rb` and add or edit this line `config.scope = "read_orders, read_products, read_themes, write_themes"`
3. Put this line to your controller: `ShopifyAPI::Asset.create(key: 'assets/angular.js', src: 'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0/angular.js')`
   where `angular.js` is my library. Just replace it with your library.
4. After pointing to that controller asset will be available in Shopify theme repository under `assets` dir

Notice, that asset once installed will be available even you uninstall you app.

Comment: Can you explain how to add in your shopify_app.rb too? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Did you notice that Shopify has an Asset resource API endpoint? You could use that to transfer a snippet from your App to the merchant's store.

Answer (score 0):

To make available of theme or any scope access point update from API need to enable

on config/initializers/omniauth.rb

:scope => 'read_orders, read_products, read_themes, write_themes',

I have added read_themes and write_themes

you have to check all the access points to be define in scope,
http://docs.shopify.com/api/tutorials/oauth